# Binding to a Date to a Kendo UI for Angular DatePicker Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

I am getting a "The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance." error when trying to bind to a Kendo UI for Datepicker or Timepicker component. [There is a page in the Kendo Docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/integration-with-json/) that talks about how to handle this scenario, but I am failing to apply it to my situation.

I am receiving data from the server and putting in my typescript object:

```
export interface Event {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  date: Date;
  startTime: Date;
  endTime?: Date;
}
```

The values end up looking like the following when debugging the typescript object:

```
id:1
name:"Event 1"
date:"2018-11-01T00:00:00"
startTime:"2018-11-01T08:30:00"
endTime:"2018-11-01T10:30:00"
```

Below is my component.ts (if I do this.event = this.parse(data.event) I don't get any errors and it seems to work, but all my fields that are not dates become random dates from the parse function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (!(this.route.snapshot.url[0].path === 'new')) {
      this.isUpdating = true;
      this.route.data
        .subscribe((data: { event: Event }) => {
          this.event = data.event;
        });
    }
  }
      public handleChange(value: Date) {
        this.event.startTime = new Date(this.intl.formatDate(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
        this.event.endTime = new Date(this.intl.formatDate(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
        this.event.date = new Date(this.intl.formatDate(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
      }

      // A simple method for the string-to-date conversion
      private parse(json) {
        Object.keys(json).map(key => {
          const date = new Date(json[key]);
          if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) { json[key] = date; }
        });

        return json;
      }
```

Below are what my components look like in the .html:

```
<kendo-datepicker [(value)]="event.date" id="date" name="date" style="width: 100%;" (valueChange)="handleChange($event)"></kendo-datepicker>

<kendo-timepicker [(value)]="event.startTime" id="startTime" name="startTime" style="width: 100%;" (valueChange)="handleChange($event)"></kendo-timepicker>

<kendo-timepicker [(value)]="event.endTime" id="endTime" name="endTime" style="width: 100%;" (valueChange)="handleChange($event)"></kendo-timepicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach does not seem very reliable. The Date constructor can create date from number as milliseconds offset from 1970. Depending on the browser formats it may also be able to create a Date from the "Event 1" string(Chrome seems to do it). I see two options here. Either try to parse the date string using specific format:

```
private parseExact(json) {
    Object.keys(json).map(key => {
      const date = this.intl.parseDate(json[key], 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss');
      if (date) { json[key] = date; }
    });

    return json;
}
```

or pass the fields that are dates:

```
private parse(json: any, dateFields: string[]) {
   for (let idx = 0; idx < dateFields.length; idx++) {
       const field = dateFields[idx]; 
       const value = json[field];
       if (value) {
         json[field] = new Date(value);
       }
   }

   return json;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1jujzo?file=app/app.component.ts